# Best practices for loading large data from Oracle to Tabular model

Tags: oracle, ssis, ssas, data-warehouse, ssas-tabular

We have created some new SSAS Tabular models which fetch data directly from Oracle. But after some testing, we found that with real customer data (with few millions of rows of data), the processing times go close to 4 hours. Our goal is to keep them under about 15mins (Due to existing system performance). We fetch from Oracle tables so query performance is not the bottleneck.

Are there any general design guides/best practices to handle such a scenario?

Comment: Actually we do have quite a lot of RAM and CPU, it is the huge data set and oracle to ssas data loading which delays as we think.

Comment: 128 Gb on both Oracle and SSAS, should be enough. We are looking for architectural patterns that others might have commonly used to solved such massive data loading.

Comment: We found that having SQL Server as a "staging database" improved performance drastically. We are considering incremental loading it using SSIS.

Comment: The standard pattern I have used/seen is Oracle > Staging > SSAS

Comment: @Jonee thanks, yes that appears to be the most feasible pattern for us as well.

Comment: @Jonee think it should be the answer

Answer (score 2):

Check your application side array fetch size as you could be experiencing network latency.
** Array fetch size note:
As per the Oracle documentation the Fetch Buffer Size is an application side memory setting that affects the number of rows returned by a single fetch.  Generally, you balance the number of rows returned with a single fetch (a.k.a. array fetch size) with the number of rows needed to be fetched.

A low array fetch size compared to the number of rows needed to be returned will manifest as delays from increased network and client side processing needed to process each fetch (i.e. the high cost of each network round trip [SQL*Net protocol]).

If this is the case, on the Oracle side you will likely see very high waits on “SQL*Net message from client”. [This wait event is posted by the session when it is waiting for a message from the client to arrive. Generally, this means that the session is just sitting idle, however, in a Client/Server environment it could also mean that either the client process is running slow or there are network latency delays. The database performance is not degraded by high wait times for this wait event.]

As I like to say: “SQL*Net is a chatty protocol”; so even though Oracle may be done with its processing of the query, excessive network round-trips results in slower response times on the client side.  One should expect that low array fetch size may be contributing to the slowness if the elapsed time to get the data into the application is much longer than the elapsed time for the DB to run the SQL; in this case app side processing time can also be a factor contributing to the slowness [you can look into app specific ways to troubleshoot/tune app side processing].

Array fetch size is not an attribute of the Oracle account nor is it an Oracle side session setting.  Array fetch size can only be set at the client; there is no DB setting for the array fetch size the client will use.  Every client application has a different mechanism for specifying the array fetch size:

- Informatica: ?? config. file param ??? setting at the connection or
  result set level?? 
  Cognos   http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21981559
- SQL*Plus:    set arraysize n
- Java/JDBC:   setFetchSize(int rows) /* method in Statement,
  PreparedStatement, CallableStatement, and ResultSet objects */
  Properties object put method “defaultRowPrefetch”
  http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/905/jdbc-javadoc/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html Another link to Oracle JDBC DefaultRowPrefetch
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html
- .Net Oracle .Net Developers Guide    The FetchSize property represents
  the total memory size in bytes that ODP.NET allocates to cache the
  data fetched from a database round-trip. The FetchSize property can
  be set on the OracleCommand, OracleDataReader, or OracleRefCursor
  object, depending on the situation. It controls the fetch size for
  filling a DataSet or DataTable using an OracleDataAdapter.
- ODBC driver: ?? something like: SetRowsetSize

Comment: We carefully evaluated parameters but we think the slowness is because of the huge volume of data.

Comment: @GayanDasanayake A huge volume of data will make array fetch size even more important.  You can also research optimizing the "session data unit" SDU; maximizing the size of the SDU will translate into lower network overhead.

Comment: The powerquery m-partions does not seem to support the fetchSize property
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/oracle-database

Comment: @GayanDasanayake Sadly, my experience is mostly with the Oracle Database, so I won't be able to assist on the PowerQuery side.